# jquery attach handler to ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery

I'm sort of stuck with a simple problem. how can I attach a handler to an element(now and future)? for example, I have a selector 'test', I apply a plugin to it:

```
$('.test').handler();
```

but this does not apply to the content loaded via ajax later.

I know that I can use `.on`, but `.on` method must take an event name as the first argument, which I think I don't have here. So is there an even name here or how do I solve this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `livequery` plugin allows you to do this:

http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

```
$(".test").livequery(function(){
    $(this).handler();
});
```

This will apply the `hander()` plugin to all current selectors, and future selectors

Comment: this looks promising. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **rebind** it in the success handler where you get the new data from ajax and inject to tht DOM

ex :

```
$.get("getNewContentForDOM.aspx",function(data){
    ("#someDiv").append(data);
    $('.test').handler();
});
```

Comment: thanks, I prefer to do it only once. without calling the code `$('.test').handler()` again. because there is a long code inside `handler(....)`